# How to construct a string of a specific format from a list of objects in Kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin

I have such class:

```
data class Box(
    val id: Long,
    val colors: List<String>,
)
```

I have `val boxes = List<Box>` and I need to print it in this format

```
id: value1; value2, value3
```

Example:

```
1: red; light blue
2: white
3: dark green; yellow; pink
```

I know that Kotlin has the ability to do this beautifully, it would be interesting to look at options for laconic solutions. Because my solution is quite ugly and probably suboptimal.

```kotlin
return boxes.map {
    "${it.id} : ${it.values.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("; "))}"
}.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
```

Comment: You wrote `id: value1; value2, value3` but did you actually mean `id: value1; value2; value3`?

Comment: If that is a natural format for your Box class, then an alternative would be to override its `toString()` method, and then you can simply call something like `boxes.mapToString("\n")` — with the benefit that other code can also call `toString()` to use the same format, and it'll also be used in logging etc.  (But it's only worth doing that if it _is_ a natural format for your class.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as follows:

```
boxes.joinToString(separator = "\n") { box ->
    "${box.id}: ${box.colors.joinToString(separator = "; ")}"
}
```